# How to change window name of schemdraw window

Tags: python, matplotlib, window, figure

I am using a schemdraw library to draw electronics schemas and I want to change the name of the displayed window from for example "Figure 1" to "Schema of XYZ".
Is it possible to change that? I know, that schemdraw library is created based on matplotlib but I wanted to try with matplotlib's funcitons and it doesnt work.

Do you have any ideas?

Reagards,
L.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use folowing

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import SchemDraw as schem   
d=schem.Drawing(3,.5,0.1,12,'sans')
#...
fig,ax = plt.subplots(num='Schema of XYZ')
#you can also try
ax.set_title('Schema of ZYX')
d.draw(ax)
```